# What's the fastest/most efficient way to count lines in Rebol?

Tags: string, performance, newline, rebol

Given a string `string`, what is the fastest/most-efficient way to count lines therein? Will accept best answers for any flavour of Rebol. I've been working under the assumption that the `parse [some [thru]]` combination was the fastest way to traverse a string, but then I don't know that for certain, hence turning to SO:

```
count-lines: func [string [string!] /local count][
    parse/all string [
        (count: 1) some [thru newline (count: count + 1)]
    ]
    count
]
```

Or:

```
count-lines: func [string [string!] /local count][
    count: 0
    until [
        count: count + 1
        not string: find/tail string newline
    ]
    count
]
```

And how about counters? How efficient is repeat?

```
count-lines: func [string [string!]][
    repeat count length? string [
        unless string: find/tail string newline [
            break/return count
        ]
    ]
]
```

**Update:** line count goes by the Text Editor principle:

[image: Empty TextMate Document]

An empty document still has a line count of one. So:

```
>> count-lines ""
== 1
>> count-lines "^/"
== 2
```

Comment: Also, any assistance testing the veracity of speed/efficiency claims would be welcome.

Comment: Rebol programmers *would* think that an empty string has 1 line.  What's with this fear of zero?  :-P

Comment: Another thing in any performance consideration is the nature of the input.  I would study any technique you try with varied input...some examples: *empty string*, *"long string of all newlines"*, *"long string of zero newlines"*...

Answer (score 4):

```
count-lines: func [
    str
    /local sort-str ][
sort-str: sort join str "^/"
1 + subtract index? find/last sort-str "^/" index? find sort-str "^/"
]
```

Comment: Interesting approach—any thoughts (anyone) how this performs?

Comment: Interesting, Darius!  BTW, we have an [SO chat room for Rebol](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol-and-red) if you'd like to join us...

Comment: Any modifying approaches are likely going to be slow for long strings because of the overhead of shifting the series over during the modifications. But the profiler will tell us which approach will be better.

Answer (score 4):

Enhanced PARSE version, as suggested by BrianH:

```
i: 1 ; add one as TextMate
parse text [any [thru newline (++ i)]]
print i
```

Comment: Should that be `++ i`? *(didn't notice there was a `++` :)*

Comment: Could also start `i: 0` and say `[newline | end] (++ i)`.

Comment: Is there a benefit/penalty using `skip` instead of `thru`? With skip, the parse rule is repeated as many times as the length of the string.

Comment: The parse approach is likely to be fastest, so I upvoted it. Still, it could use a little work. You might consider using `to` or `thru`, for instance.

Comment: Chris, initializing to 0 and then doing that block will not only be slower, but would result in an endless loop in R2: `any [end]` will never stop at the end of the string in R2. But it would be slower because `parse` has to recurse into the nested block, and then backtrack through the alternate (the part after the `|`). So, it's better to initialize to 1 instead. It's faster to use `thru` than `skip`, and makes the rule simpler too (exercise for rebolek, but as a hint: you don't need `end`, or to backtrack).

Comment: Of course, d'oh! My inclination is to have the count fully contained within the rule, but inclinations aren't always rational.

Comment: If you want the count contained, move the initialization into the rule, like this: `(i: 1)`

Comment: Well, I used `skip` instead of `thru` because I wrote this reply just to gain enough points to join chat... But I like `parse` and `parse` answer was missing, so I wrote something :)

Comment: If I may one-lineify it:
`count-lines: func [text [string!] /i][parse text [(i: 1) any [thru newline (++ i)]] i]`

Comment: @rgchris You mean `/local i` I take it.  :-)

Comment: @HostileFork `/i` also creates a local. `/local` is a convention that has no formal meaning. Though I would use `/local` in a formal setting.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the best simple non-`parse` version I can think of:

```
count-lines: function [text [string!]] [
    i: 1
    find-all text newline [++ i]
    i
]
```

It uses `function` and `++` from more recent versions of Rebol, and `find-all` from either R3 or R2/Forward. You could look at the source of `find-all` and inline what you find and optimize, but situations like this are exactly what we wrote `find-all` for, so why not use it?

Comment: Rebolek's `parse` solution is likely faster, but only a profiler can say for sure.

Comment: Another interesting new function, thks!

Comment: The `find-all` function is a good candidate to change to a native.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the best for me:

```
temp: read/lines %mytext.txt
length? temp
```

Comment: The string source is not a file, do you mean to write the string to a file in order to read/lines?

Comment: OK, then we'll have to add the overhead of writing out the value to the file, then reading it back. Or you can try `deline/lines`, which does the same thing in memory without needing a file. Watch out though: In R2, `deline/lines` is mezzanine, so it won't be as fast as some of the other solutions. In R3 it's native. Regardless, `read/lines` and `deline/lines` make a copy of the source string, so we'll have to see if that overhead overwhelms the advantage of being a single native call. I can confirm this approach works though.

Comment: BriaH is a real programmer, I just propose solution. If you need time optimization or other hight technical solution, contact him. :-)

Answer (score 2):

remove-each can be fast as it is native

```
s: "1^/2^/3"
a: length? s
print a - length? remove-each v s [v = #"^/"]
; >> 2
```

or as a function

```
>> f: func [s] [print [(length? s) - (length? remove-each v s [v = #"^/"])]]
>> f "1^/2^/3"
== 2
```

Comment: I'd need to benchmark this against the `'parse` function above to see which is faster. I'd also worry that `'s` would need to be copied so as not to modify the original string thereby hampering efficiency.

Comment: Style Notes: function returns the number of newlines, not the number of lines—should return `s + 1` per the 'Text Editor Principle' (see question).

Comment: Note that in Rebol 3, REMOVE-EACH returns the removal count, not the modified series. So your suggestion can just be `remove-each v s [v = #"^/"]` in Rebol 3. (And that is actually the first use case I ever came across where the rather weird return value of REMOVE-EACH in R3 is useful.)

Answer (score 2):

Why no one came with the simplest solution I wonder :)

```
t: "abc^/de^/f^/ghi"
i: 0 until [i: i + 1 not t: find/tail t newline] i
== 4
```

Not sure about the performance but I think it's quite fast, as UNTIL and FIND are natives.
WHILE could be used as well.

```
i: 1 while [t: find/tail t newline] [i: i + 1] i
== 4
```

Just need to check for empty string. And if it would be a function, argument series needs to be HEADed.

Comment: The `while` solution here is what I meant by my "inline `find-all` and optimize" comment. The `until` solution might be faster, since `until` is a simpler native. `i: i + 1` is faster than `++ i` in R2, but slower in R3.

Answer (score 2):

Not the most efficient, but probably one of the fastest solution (anyway if a benchmark is run, I would like to see how this solution performs):

```
>> s: "1^/2^/ ^/^/3"
>> (length? s) - length? trim/with copy s newline
== 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not know about performance, and the last line rule (r3).

```
>> length? parse "1^/2^/3" "^/"
== 3
```

Comment: My concern here is that it creates as many new strings as there is lines—it's a very concise one-liner, but I fear it does more than the `parse` example in the question. Would like to hear other opinions...

Comment: The other downside to this approach is a quirk in using `parse` as `split`—it breaks under this condition: `parse {one^/"two^/three"} "^/"`

Comment: Good points. i doubt the extra memory would be a concern. i cheat and do not benchmark the extra gc :)
But the quote-handling is a bad surprise.

Answer (score 0):

hehehe the read/lines length? temp is a great thing I though about read/lines -> foreach lines temps [ count: count + 1]

another way to do it would be to do

```
temp: "line 1 ^M line2 ^M  line3 ^M "
length? parse temp newline ; that cuts the strings into a block 
;of multiple strings that represent each a line [ "line 1" "line2" "line3" ] 
:then you count how much  strings you have in the block with length?
```

I like to code in rebol it is so funny

Edit I didnt read the whole post so my solution already waas proposed in a different way...

ok to amend for my sin of posting a already posted solution I will bring insight comment of a unexpected behavior of that solution.  Multiple chained carriage returns are not counted (using rebol3 linux ...)

```
>> a: "line1 ^M line2 ^M line3 ^M^M"
== "line1 ^M line2 ^M line3 ^M^M"

>> length? parse a newline 
== 3
```